# Fragment does not show up when app starts (onCreate) but does when it resumes (onResume)

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I'm having an issue where a fragment in my main activity does not show up when the app is being started initially (during the main apps onCreate method) but does show up when I pause the app and then resume it (during the onResume method)

Here's the important parts of my main activity
activity_main.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" />               

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
    </FrameLayout>
```

MainActivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    protected FrameLayout fragment_container;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        if (findViewById(R.id.fragment_container) != null) {
            if (savedInstanceState != null) {
                TextViewFragment fragment = new TextViewFragment();
                fragment.setArguments(getIntent().getExtras());

                getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.fragment_container, fragment).commit();
            }
        }}
```

TextViewFragment:

```
public class TextViewFragment extends Fragment {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstance) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstance);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.textview_fragment, container, false);
    }

}
```

textview_fragment:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:text="This is not showing up"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:typeface="sans"
        android:textSize="35sp"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When it starts first then  if (savedInstanceState != null) { condition gives null.

You may remove the condition then it will load the fragment always.

Comment: Yup you got, rookie mistake